# Dynamically Obfuscate HTML

Tags: html, obfuscation

I was wondering if there was any way to dynamically obfuscate html on a live server but not offline, so soon as my website was visited the source would be obfuscated rather than in plain text.

Comment: What do you hope to gain from that?

Comment: Nothing, i'm just seeing if it was possible is all.

Comment: Well, you can't really "obfuscate" HTML because it has to be in a defined structure with defined tag names.  However, you can strip all comments, remove all non-significant whitespaces etc. which make the whole thing a **tiny** bit less easy to read.  But anyone with a modern browser can just turn on its developer tools and dump out the HTML in indented, nice-to-read format.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using php, IonCube has a plugin. it can be found here: http://www.ioncube.com/html_encoder.php it turns your html page into minified javascript.

Comment: yeah you do run into the people that do not turn on javascript but it does happen. You cannot really obfuscate the code anyother way. Everything else out there just puts it all on one line and adds spacing but most browsers when viewing source partially compansate for that.

Comment: @Lord_Dracon, the answer was relevent at the time as PHP 5.5 was not released for almost 5 years after this answer. Any answer you find from before a release will not be tested in newer versions. So, why the downvote?

Comment: For those who come here to know that the answer is outdated nowadays. It may have been relevant at the time but it wasted my time until I discovered that it no longer works.

Comment: @Lord_Dracon so leave a comment. Obscuring HTML code is an out dated process as it is easy to undue. Most that still do it today use other tools built with NodeJS/NPM repositories to assist in obfuscation today. In addition the link even states it doesn't work with newer than PHP 5.4, so it shouldn't have wasted much time.

Answer (score 9):

Since the client (browser) will have to parse it into a sensible DOM tree, this is pretty much fruitless. These days it's a lot more common to inspect a site using Firebug/Webkit Inspector, which provides a nicely formatted, navigable tree. Most people won't even notice that the HTML is "obfuscated", much less be stopped by it.

Executable code can be obfuscated by minimizing variable names and such without changing the result. HTML *is* the result though, if you change anything about it, the result will change. So "obfuscation" would mostly be limited to creative use of spacing anyway.

Comment: @Samuel Exactly my point, any decent inspection tool will just glance over it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The real question you should ask yourself is "why do I need to obfuscate HTML?". If you're hiding sensitive information, then you should be either encrypting that data, or never presenting it to the client.

Most sensitive information or transactions should take place on the server, and the client only receives a token, or encrypted information, or a unique transaction identifier that can be passed back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

Let me put it this way: There's no way to dynamically obfuscate the HTML on your site such that any reasonably competent person couldn't get it anyway.

1. You could use JavaScript to attempt to obfuscate it, but you'd have to do it in a way that didn't actually affect the DOM.
2. You could generate the contents of the page itself with JavaScript, but that is likely to damage accessibility, and once again the DOM will have to be in a condition the browser can use.
3. You could insert massive amounts of whitespace into the source, but that is easily overcome as well.

All this, and you make it harder and more annoying to manage your site. Minification has its purpose, but obfuscation here is lose-lose.

Answer (score 0):

Your could search for and remove all tabs, newlines, extra spaces, and comments