# Hide web markup or encrypt it?

Tags: html

I am wondering if there is anyway to hide Mark-up or Code within a webpage; I know this isn't a type of thing meant to be done; but I am wondering if there is any way possible of publishing a working web page or what have you. And **completely hide, encrypting or allowing the Web mark-up and code to not be legibly viewable or accessible?**

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206630/dynamically-obfuscate-html

Comment: _this_ is just wrong, go to View Source and see what you did!!

Comment: I was just curious; apparently a no-no question. Sorry, feel free to flag or do whatever.

Comment: Why did you downvote this question so hard?

Comment: Yeah, I sure got reamed on this one. Was just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers above is the short version of what I would say.

First, regarding the mark-up, the simple "no" is almost everything which can be said. The browser has to know, what to display and has to get this information in a "browser-readable" way. There might be a few exceptions, if you wan't to hide PARTS of the mark-up, but I think this has not to do with your question (e.g. using some kind of applet...crap).

To the "code": there are methods to obfuscate your client-side code. If you want to see this in action, take a look at [uglify.js](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2). On the github page you will find an online demo, where you can test it with every javascript code you like. After you "mangled" and "minified" your code with this, it will still work, but variables etc. will have senseless (and short) names, technical not neccesary whitespace and linebreaks will be removed etc. So for a human it's hard to get which part of your code does what. Depending on the size of your webapp it's likely that it will be far easier to rewrite the functionality of your application than to understand the obfusticated code.

A "workaround" for a "real hide" is to move parts of you app logic to the backend, so the browser will mostly get static content. But in times of fast and responsive webapplications this isn't what you want in the most cases.

Answer (score 3):

Markup, no. Code can be obfuscated, but it's always possible to deobfuscate it (even if the output is not very readable). So the closest you get is making obfuscated JavaScript output your HTML markup. In this case, "view source" won't show any readly readable markup. But tools like Chrome Inspector and Firebug will.

Answer (score 1):

No. There are ways to make it a little harder to read for the casual surfer, but nothing that can't be undone with relative ease.